# How can I understand the 2nd solution of this equation? (theoretically correct, but doesn't work while being verified)

Tags: complex, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve these two equations:
$$
\cos\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_0\qquad e^{i\beta'}\sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right) = g_1
$$
Where $g_0$ is real and $g_1$ is complex. From the discussions on the math channel, we can find that
$$
\gamma'=2\cos^{-1}(g_0),\qquad e^{i\beta'}=\pm\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}\qquad\beta'=-i\log\frac{g_1}{\sqrt{1-g_0^2}}+k\pi,\ \text{where}\ k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
However, I'm still having trouble understanding the solution when $k$ is an odd number, say if it equals $1$, then I'm trying to verify the solution using Mathematica:

Given that

`g_0 = 0.8974187611347583, g_1= -0.33540402107889095+0.28660723962849705*I`

We can find $\gamma' = 0.913825694123124 , \beta_1'= 2.434484141132717 , \beta_2'=5.5760767947225105$ (differ by $1*\pi$).

However, when I tried to use Mathematica to verify the solutions, only $\beta_1'$ and $\gamma'$ works, by which I mean $e^{i\beta'}\sin\left(\frac{\gamma'}{2}\right)-g_1=0$.

When I plug $\beta_2', \gamma'$ into the equation, it returns `0.670808 - 0.573214 I`. Why the second answer doesn't work? Thanks a lot for the help!!

PS: This is what I tried:
`Exp[I*5.5760767947225105]* Sin[0.913825694123124/2] - (-0.33540402107889095 +  0.28660723962849705*I) // Simplify`

Comment: The solution is not correct for odd $k$.  `Solve` reveals this; the general solution involves distinct arbitrary multiples of $4\pi$ and $2\pi$, as well as a coupled choice of sign.

Comment: @Adam Thanks a lot for the comment!! Could you explain a bit more about the coupled choice of sign? Why does the general solution involve distinct arbitrary multiples of $4\pi$ and $2\pi$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqns = {Cos[γ/2] == g0, Exp[I*β] Sin[γ/2] == g1};

sol = Solve[eqns, {β, γ}] // Simplify
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
sol // TrigToExp
```

[image]

Verifying the solutions,

```
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers],
 eqns /. sol // Simplify]

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

For your specific values,

```
val = {g0 -> 0.8974187611347583, 
   g1 -> -0.33540402107889095 + 0.28660723962849705*I};

sol2 = sol /. val
```

[image]

```
Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers],
 eqns /. val /. sol2 // Simplify]

(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! ! What does the last section mean? (`Assuming[Element[{C[1], C[2]}, Integers],
 eqns /. val /. sol2 // Simplify]`)

Comment: Starting with the general equations, substitute your specific values so that `g0` and `g1` are replaced, then substitute using `sol2` so that `beta` and `gamma` are replaced with their values, then `Simplify` using the assumptions that the arbitrary constants (`C[1]` and `C[2]`) are integers. Read the documentation on `ReplaceAll` (i.e., `/.`).

Comment: Thanks!! Could you also explain a little bit about the output?  `(* {{True, True}, {True, True}} *)`

Comment: Look at the output for `Clear[x]; x^2 == 4 /. {{x -> -2}, {x -> 2}}`  Look at documentation for `Equal`